# error when use cvReleaseImage in backgroundWorker c++

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, c++-cli

don't work cvReleaseImage for Cleaning memory in backgroundWorker c++

```
IplImage* image2 = NULL;
image2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(frame1.cols, frame1.rows), 8, 3);
IplImage ipltemp = frame1;
cvCopy(&ipltemp, image2);
pictureBox_frame->Image = gcnew //replacement of cvShowIma
System::Drawing::Bitmap(image2->width, image2->height, image2->widthStep,
System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, (System::IntPtr)image2->imageData);

**cvReleaseImage(&image2);**
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using the **obsolete** C api?

Comment: i use opencv c++ library and i want show image processing result in picturebox  visual c++